# How can I breaking up a 12 million interaction network into sub networks

Tags: algorithm, networking, data-structures, bigdata

I have a 3 column list which represents a network with the following structure:

```
geneA geneB Spearman_Value
```

There are 12 million interactions which make up this list.  I would like to find sub-networks which exist in this larger network where the Spearman values are similar.  What I have been thinking of doing is breaking the list up into many different pieces and working on each piece with a different node from our computing cluster.  One issue is that the nodes need to be able to see other parts of the list to determine if the interaction that they are looking at is a part of some other sub network.  At first I thought I should use a hash because it would allow for searches in O(1) time, but this would result in over writing of keys and or values.  I have been thinking of creating a data structure where each sub network is a linked list and they are all tied together in some larger structure like a hash. I am not sure if this even makes sense because I don't know how to make each key in some way identify the different sub network in any meaningful manner.

Comment: I'm no expert in this topic, but here's a couple wikipedia articles that may be of interest: [Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) and [Distributed hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)

Comment: You may want to look into cluster analysis.

Comment: Hi @dfeuer I looked at KNN, K-means, and hierarchical clustering but the issue is more with how to construct a data structure where the different compute nodes can all work on.  I could perform clustering on each portion of the network but then each compute node might miss something.  Thank you though.

Comment: Why would a hash overwrite values? The only time that would happen is if you don't have a collision resolution strategy. But any decent hash table already handles that.

Comment: @JimMischel when I initially created the hash my values were being overwritten. The keys would not be unique in many cases. If I use gene A or gene B as the key then the value would be overwritten by the new value, where as what I would like to happen is when it sees that gene A or B is in the subnetwork of the next key it would tack that value onto the list. Hence the desire to use a linked list. I have never had to solve a problem such as this so it is all new to me. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we went with using wcgna to solve this problem and performed the work on our cluster:
[WCGNA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WGCNA/index.html)